# RuntimeException: Unable to write in the "cache" directory at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer()

Tags: php

```
protected function buildContainer()
{
    foreach (['cache' => $this->getCacheDir(), 'build' => $this->warmupDir ?: $this->getBuildDir(), 'logs' => $this->getLogDir()] as $name => $dir) {
        if (!is_dir($dir)) {
            if (false === @mkdir($dir, 0777, true) && !is_dir($dir)) {
                throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Unable to create the "%s" directory (%s).', $name, $dir));
            }
        } elseif (!is_writable($dir)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Unable to write in the "%s" directory (%s).', $name, $dir));
        }
    }
```

i am trying to configure uvdesk on test server but getting RuntimeException:

> Unable to write in the "cache" directory   at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer()

Comment: There's a similar problem in [acquia/cli#219](https://github.com/acquia/cli/issues/219) which was caused by using too old PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

> i am trying to configure uvdesk on test server but getting RuntimeException: Unable to write in the "cache" directory at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer()

It looks like a file/directory permission problem. The directory has to be writeable by the webserver. After creating the directory you should adjust the permissions with the below commands:

- chown -R www-data:www-data var/cache
- chown -R www-data:www-data var/log
- chown -R www-data:www-data var

or

- chmod -R 777 var/log              [for give permission]

It would ideally be better for you to reach out over at the official [uvdesk forum](https://forums.uvdesk.com/) regarding your queries.

Comment: having window OS C:\xampp\htdocs\uvdesk\uvdesk-community-v1.1.3\var\cache\dev>chown -R www-data:www-data var/cache
'chown' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: To solve the issue by installing "Git for Windows" and adding the "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" path to the system %PATH% environment variable. 

You need to check if the command’s location is added to the PATH. If it’s not, you can add the command’s location to the "PATH".

More references here
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html

https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm